# CockroachDB Unordered Row ID

Tags: sql, database, cockroachdb

Why does CockroachDB add a `rowid` column to my tables? They are `INT` values and do not look ordered, does this column give up the sort order and/or impact how range scans work?

Comment: there is no order to a table by definition

Answer (score 3):

CockroachDB automatically adds a `rowid` column that serves as a primary key if no primary key is specified for the table. `rowid` values are generated as a combination of the insert timestamp and the ID of the node executing the statement, as such, ordering is maintained.

To create your own `rowid`, two functions are commonly used:

- `unique_rowid()`: ensures a unique integer for a primary key, value always increases
- `unordered_unique_rowid()`: ensures a unique integer for a primary key but the `rowid` value does **not** always increase. Having `rowid` values that do not always increase helps divide the key-space more evenly, preventing range hotspots.

Helpful docs from CockroachDB:
[Create a table](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/create-table.html#create-a-table)
[Auto-generate unique row ids](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/sql-faqs.html#how-do-i-auto-generate-unique-row-ids-in-cockroachdb)
[ID generation functions](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v22.1/functions-and-operators#id-generation-functions)

Helpful Blog Post:
[CockroachDB Key Generation Part 3 - Unordered RowID](https://glennfawcett.wpcomstaging.com/2022/06/27/cockroachdb-key-generation-part3-unordered-rowid/)